# React native fast lane: upload to TestFlight fail with java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

I just start deploying fastlane to my project, then I got this error when it come to upload_to_testflight step like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPVQN.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eypMd.png). Has anyone face this issue? Please give a solution. Thank you

#### Stack

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| OS | 12.3.1 |
| Ruby | 3.1.2 |
| Bundler? | false |
| Git | git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132) |
| Installation Source | /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.211.0/libexec/bin/fastlane |
| Host | macOS 12.3.1 (21E258) |
| Ruby Lib Dir | /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.2_1/lib |
| OpenSSL Version | OpenSSL 1.1.1s 1 Nov 2022 |
| Is contained | false |
| Is homebrew | true |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | false |
| Xcode Path | /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version | 13.2.1 |
| Swift Version | 5.5.2 |

#### System Locale

| Variable | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LANG | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LC_ALL | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LANGUAGE |  |  |

#### fastlane files:

**No Fastfile found**

**No Appfile found**

#### fastlane gems

| Gem | Version | Update-Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fastlane | 2.211.0 | ✅ Up-To-Date |

#### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**

**Loaded gems**

| Gem | Version |
| --- | --- |
| error_highlight | 0.3.0 |
| did_you_mean | 1.6.1 |
| atomos | 0.1.3 |
| rexml | 3.2.5 |
| CFPropertyList | 3.0.5 |
| claide | 1.1.0 |
| colored2 | 3.1.2 |
| nanaimo | 0.3.0 |
| xcodeproj | 1.22.0 |
| rouge | 2.0.7 |
| xcpretty | 0.3.0 |
| terminal-notifier | 2.0.0 |
| unicode-display_width | 1.8.0 |
| terminal-table | 1.8.0 |
| plist | 3.6.0 |
| public_suffix | 5.0.0 |
| addressable | 2.8.1 |
| multipart-post | 2.0.0 |
| word_wrap | 1.0.0 |
| optparse | 0.1.1 |
| tty-screen | 0.8.1 |
| tty-cursor | 0.7.1 |
| tty-spinner | 0.9.3 |
| artifactory | 3.0.15 |
| babosa | 1.0.4 |
| colored | 1.2 |
| highline | 2.0.3 |
| commander | 4.6.0 |
| excon | 0.94.0 |
| faraday-em_http | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-em_synchrony | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-excon | 1.1.0 |
| faraday-httpclient | 1.0.1 |
| faraday-multipart | 1.0.4 |
| faraday-net_http | 1.0.1 |
| faraday-net_http_persistent | 1.2.0 |
| faraday-patron | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-rack | 1.0.0 |
| faraday-retry | 1.0.3 |
| ruby2_keywords | 0.0.5 |
| faraday | 1.10.2 |
| unf_ext | 0.0.8.2 |
| unf | 0.1.4 |
| domain_name | 0.5.20190701 |
| http-cookie | 1.0.5 |
| faraday-cookie_jar | 0.0.7 |
| faraday_middleware | 1.2.0 |
| fastimage | 2.2.6 |
| gh_inspector | 1.1.3 |
| mini_magick | 4.11.0 |
| naturally | 2.2.1 |
| rubyzip | 2.3.2 |
| security | 0.1.3 |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.1 |
| dotenv | 2.8.1 |
| bundler | 2.3.11 |
| simctl | 1.6.8 |
| jwt | 2.5.0 |
| uber | 0.1.0 |
| declarative | 0.0.20 |
| trailblazer-option | 0.1.2 |
| representable | 3.2.0 |
| retriable | 3.1.2 |
| mini_mime | 1.1.2 |
| memoist | 0.16.2 |
| multi_json | 1.15.0 |
| os | 1.1.4 |
| signet | 0.17.0 |
| googleauth | 1.3.0 |
| httpclient | 2.8.3 |
| webrick | 1.7.0 |
| google-apis-core | 0.9.1 |
| google-apis-playcustomapp_v1 | 0.12.0 |
| google-apis-androidpublisher_v3 | 0.31.0 |
| google-cloud-env | 1.6.0 |
| google-cloud-errors | 1.3.0 |
| google-cloud-core | 1.6.0 |
| google-apis-iamcredentials_v1 | 0.16.0 |
| google-apis-storage_v1 | 0.19.0 |
| rake | 13.0.6 |
| digest-crc | 0.6.4 |
| google-cloud-storage | 1.44.0 |
| emoji_regex | 3.2.3 |
| jmespath | 1.6.1 |
| aws-eventstream | 1.2.0 |
| aws-sigv4 | 1.5.2 |
| aws-sdk-core | 3.167.0 |
| aws-sdk-kms | 1.59.0 |
| aws-sdk-s3 | 1.117.1 |
| set | 1.0.2 |
| json | 2.6.2 |
| aws-partitions | 1.661.0 |
| forwardable | 1.3.2 |
| logger | 1.5.0 |
| pathname | 0.2.0 |
| shellwords | 0.1.0 |
| cgi | 0.3.1 |
| date | 3.2.2 |
| timeout | 0.2.0 |
| stringio | 3.0.1 |
| securerandom | 0.1.1 |
| uri | 0.11.0 |
| openssl | 3.0.0 |
| digest | 3.1.0 |
| io-nonblock | 0.1.0 |
| ipaddr | 1.2.4 |
| io-wait | 0.2.1 |
| zlib | 2.1.1 |
| resolv | 0.2.1 |
| time | 0.2.0 |
| open-uri | 0.2.0 |
| mutex_m | 0.1.1 |
| net-protocol | 0.1.2 |
| net-http | 0.2.0 |
| ostruct | 0.5.2 |
| english | 0.7.1 |
| erb | 2.2.3 |
| strscan | 3.0.1 |
| abbrev | 0.1.0 |
| io-console | 0.5.11 |
| tempfile | 0.1.2 |
| delegate | 0.2.0 |
| fileutils | 1.6.0 |
| tmpdir | 0.1.2 |
| base64 | 0.1.1 |
| singleton | 0.1.1 |
| open3 | 0.1.1 |
| nkf | 0.1.1 |
| prettyprint | 0.1.1 |
| pp | 0.3.0 |
| find | 0.1.1 |
| yaml | 0.2.0 |
| psych | 4.0.3 |

Comment: how are you uploading your file. you can easily upload with XCode.

Comment: Yes, I can. I just want to implement fastlane in my project to automate some tedious task like build and upload file to Google Play, App Store

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `fastlane env`?

Comment: I just add my fastlane env to my question, please review it @AaronBrager

Comment: Fastlane install looks good as far as I can tell. I suggest a next troubleshooting step to install  Transporter from the Max App Store, add the IPA file which fastlane generated, and ask Transporter to verify if the app is valid. If not it will hopefully give you a better error message.  One other idea I had is you could try updating to Xcode 14, I’m not sure whether Apple is still taking submissions from Xcode 13.

Comment: Thanks for advising, I solved my problem by set variable ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD to true